# While using chrome.debugger api it closes automatically and says target closed but the tab is still open, Can anyone help please?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is the relevant part of the code.
I am trying to capture network calls using chrome.debugger API here. Everything is ok but once the page loads or I click a link then after the first action it closes automatically

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
      if (message.play) {
        if (message.captureNtwrk) {
          chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
            const tab = tabs[0];
            tabId = tab.id;
            chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId: tabId }, version, onAttach.bind(null, tabId));
          });
        }
        if (message.captureScreen) {
        }
        if (message.captureEvent) {
        }
      }
      if (message.stop) {
        chrome.debugger.detach({ tabId: tabId });
      }
    });

    // Function to run while debugging
    const onAttach = (tabId) => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: tabId }, 'Network.enable');
      chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
      chrome.debugger.onDetach.addListener((source, reason) => {
        console.log('Detached: ' + reason);
      });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling other extensions, especially 3rd party extensions added by desktop applications. One particular extension observed, which causes debugger to detach after page navigation is Adobe Acrobat.